# Clustering Road Networks at various Radii

Tags: clustering

I have numerous road segments that belong to a city. Each road segment as a weight that is given to it due to its level of 'connectivity' (‘impact’from a small side street to a motorway). So, small neighbourhood road networks won’t have much weight at the regional level. These are calculated at different radii from each segment going from 400 meters at 400 meter intervals to 20,000 m. So each line segment will have a ‘measure’ at each radius (400, 800, 1200m) that indicate its level of impact on the total network.

Now here’s my question:

I want to be able to 'cluster' these so I can say that these segments 'cluster' around the R400 (400m) radius and therefore are local BUT also have activity around 800m and 1000m so could be local and a little peripheral activity. So below are 6 records just showing the activity at 400, 800 and 1200 meters - in reality it'll go up to 20,000m at 400m intevals.

```
  400m       800m        1200m
```

1     1.2982806      1.3231481       1.3453017
2     1.2048655      1.2961186       1.3369008
3     1.2557751      1.3028713       1.341819
4     1.3692737      1.367762        1.3970656
5     1.3519189      1.3815914       1.3904856
6     1.3940601      1.3942301       1.4031725

So the higher the score the greater the 'connectivity' at that level of radius. So 400m radius of the 2nd record start at 1.20 then at 1200m is 1.33 - so it has a higher connectivity at 1200m.

Therefore, I think the 'shape' of the 'line' and how it clusters with similar lines is important. But I want the data to dictate this and not me starting to create 'categories' by forcing the data to do things that I want to see - this is my concern.

I was thinking using the K Mean measure (But this asks for number of categories...which I think dictates to the data what I want to see) or comparing areas under the curves Or shapes of the curves once of plotted them out – basically grouping the once that look similar, but I know that there are issues where because they could be same areas and shapes but inverted.

thanks for your patience, clearly, I am rather lost...
would be grateful for any advice!
with kindest regards,
Atakan

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried visualizing your data? If it doesn't cluster visually, the algorithms will likely not find anything either.

Maybe you could improve your question by just adding a plot of say, 100-500 such lines, maybe labeled ones (small streets, motorways in different colors?).

See: cluster analysis won't do magic. It needs guideance in choosing the algorithms, distance functions, data normalization and algorithm parameters carefully. We will not be able to give you a short answer like "use k-means" without knowing your data. And even then, you will have to try out a *lot* of things.

But the first thing to do clearly is to visualize your data. Because also after running clustering, you *will* want to visualize it to see if it somewhat worked.